# Showing list of images in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I need to show the list of images in part of longlist selector. I have list persons bound to each control in longlistselector datatemplate.

How do I bind the image as we bind name of the person to textblock ? I have the images stored in shared location.

I tried setting the binding to a model property which gives the complete path of the image. But that didn't work.

Can some one point me the example which does this kind of binding in windows phone?

Thanks in advance.

-Sudheer

Comment: change the data template and make a image control in and bid its source property..to image path string property..